# When I try to upload my package to PyPI why do I get an upload failed?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

The upload failed and I see there is a warning that MANIFEST.in does not exist and standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt, README.rst.

Can someone please help? I'm not sure if I need to create the manifest template and standard readme files or if there's something wrong with the code I'm using:

```
C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Projects\Head_First_Python\nester>python setup.py sdist upload
running sdist
running check
warning: sdist: manifest template 'MANIFEST.in' does not exist (using default file list)

warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt, README.rst

writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating nester-1.0.0
making hard links in nester-1.0.0...
hard linking nester.py -> nester-1.0.0
hard linking setup.py -> nester-1.0.0
Creating tar archive
removing 'nester-1.0.0' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist\nester-1.0.0.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for details
error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for details

C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Projects\Head_First_Python\nester>
```

Comment: Those files (`MANIFEST.in`, and `README*`) are not strictly necessary. They are not your actual problem here. The authentication or authorization (i.e. username and password) seem to be the problem. Make sure those are correct.

Comment: So I just checked my username and password and they are correct. I have python and pip installed. Now I'm following a tutorial on https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi. I try to use this command and get an error:   C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Projects\Head_First_Python\nester>python setup.py bdist_wheel
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Comment: Maybe the [`wheel`](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/) project is missing in your environment.